# Flash animation effect using CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I want to implement some animation in CSS3 which has an effect like its been coded in flash.
I was looking for some effect which looks like the opening credits of a movie, when the credits keep getting displayed at various positions of the screen while the movie is playing in the background. Only thing instead of using a movie here I want to use images.
Looking for something like this: [Madmanimation](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/content/demo/madmanimation/)

Comment: tried following the code of the site given above, wanted to learn how to animate the things in the images in my own style.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: here you go:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A really simple example](http://dabblet.com/gist/3726572) I just did.

HTML:

```
<h1>That's all!</h1>
<div class='bg'><h3>Pencil Nebula</h3></div>
<div class='bg'><h3>N44 in the Large Magellanic Cloud</h3></div>
<div class='bg'><h3>Messier 83: Central Region</h3></div>
<div class='bg'><h3>Dark Matter</h3></div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 7em;
    color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    animation: endani 1s 17s forwards;
}
.bg, h3 { position: absolute; }
.bg {
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
}
.bg:first-of-type {
    background-image: 
        url(http://i.space.com/images/i/21536/wW4/pencil-nebula-wide-1920.jpg);
    animation: bgani 5s;
}
.bg:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: 
        url(http://i.space.com/images/i/20755/wW4/N44-Large-Magellanic-Cloud.jpg);
    animation: bgani 5s 4s;
}
.bg:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-image: 
        url(http://i.space.com/images/i/20683/wW4/eso-messier-83.jpg);
    animation: bgani 5s 8s;
}
.bg:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-image: 
        url(http://i.space.com/images/i/15679/wW4/hubble-cluster-abell-520.jpg);
    animation: bgani 5s 12s;
}
h3 {
    padding: .2em .8em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.65);
    color: white;
}
.bg:first-of-type h3 { top: 25%; left: 15%; }
.bg:nth-of-type(2) h3 { bottom: 25%; right: 15%; }
.bg:nth-of-type(3) h3 { top: 25%; right: 15%; }
.bg:nth-of-type(4) h3 { bottom: 25%; left: 15%; }

@keyframes bgani { 
    0% { opacity: 0; } 20% { opacity: 1; }
    95% { opacity: 1; } 100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes endani { to { color: crimson; text-shadow: 0 0 2px white; } }
```

This one uses four elements (displayed one on top of the other) which have their opacity animated (you fade in the element you want to appear by changing its `opacity` from 0 to 1 and you fade out the one you want to hide by changing its `opacity` from 1 to 0), but there are numerous other options, like animating a `scale` transform (you scale to 0 the element you want to disappear, and from 0 to 1 the element you want to appear) or animating `top`/ `right`/ `bottom`/ `left` values to move the elements on and offscreen.

Also, you could have just one element with multiple backgrounds and then animate their `background-size` or `background-position` (that's strictly for switching the images, you'd have to synchronize the changing text with the changing images... or leave them unsynchronized for a more chaotic effect).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into CSS3 animations using keyframes and transformations.
[Start here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: I was looking into some tutorial to help me with animating images using CSS3 in such a way that they seem like a movie. And also display some texts while the images are in transition.

Comment: Keyframe animations can do all that.